# Blog Archives - Side Cut Off and Column Sizes

Tags: wordpress, archive

I'm working on: https://holisticharmonyinhc.com/ via Wordpress

The homepage is currently set to display the Archives, and if you notice, the main section (not the sidebar) is being partially cut off on the right. The Single Post display do not seem to have this issue, only the Archives display. Wondering how this can be corrected.

Also wondering if it's possible / how to adjust the columns of the Archive display where the feature image is set to a 2:3 ratio (width:height) and the info of the post is centered vertically.

I'm not positive what coding is needed for me to provide, but happy to provide anything requested. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS in your active theme style.css file

```
.ruby-section .ruby-content-wrap {
    overflow: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to accomplish the second ask (of altering the column sizes and vertically centering the column with the text content)?

Comment: I didnt understand that. Could you please explain?

Comment: Right now when looking at the archives view, the columns in the main section (not the sidebar) are split 50/50. I would like to decrease the size of the left column, display the image (cropped) at a 2:3 ratio (width:height), and vertically-align the text to the middle in the right column. Similar to this: https://karalydon.com/blog/ ...  but with the text vertically aligned to the middle. The column width and image proportions are my main goal; the vertical-align is not needed as much. Hope this makes more sense! Let me know if you need more clarification!

Comment: Similar to how you have in the image would be great, but would like the image to display with a vertical crop. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Need to change in PHP files.